# Tableview inside a scrollview inside another scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

So I have an issue at the moment I am trying to put tableviews inside a scrollview which is inside another scrollview. Is this possible?

Think of it like this. I have a parent view which scrolls left and right between pages, on a page there is another scrollview. Inside the scrollview (page 1) there are 3 tableviews.

First off I just want to know if this is possible.

Parent Scrollview - Top view

Page 1 - scrollview

--Tableview 1

--Tableview 2

--Tableview 3

-Page 2 - scrollview

--Tableview 1

--Tableview 2

--Tableview 3

Comment: Dont forget to know, tableviews already having scrollview.. It means, In a single page(not in single view controller) you are having 5 Scrollviews.. handle it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible, you will just have to have advanced detection as to which scrollview/tableview should receive the scrolls.

Check out the [official Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html) for more info on how to do this.

Comment: cool thanks, where should I start with the advanced detection? e.g. how do I detect. I need to be iOS 4.3 > compatible

Comment: hm, that link doesn't appear to have anything useful anymore. Just do a search here for "nested scrollviews" and you will find a ton of useful information.

Comment: Yep, the link just says that this should "work automatically".  Tried it and it definitely does _not_.

Comment: It does work, at least whenever I have had to nest them, so perhaps you are not implementing it correctly or have some sort of misconfigured setting